# AuthorizationPolicy `.RequireRole()` does not work

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-authorization

my authorization policy does not work the way I expect it to. It's always evaluating `false` although all the conditions are met, as can be seen below. I have experimented in defining the role claim type name a few different ways because this is what I have seen most people do, but nothing seems to work. Does someone have an idea on how to proceed further with the debugging?

##### Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("EntraExternalIdentities", options.ProviderOptions);
    // options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
    // options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
    // options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = ClaimTypes.Role;
});

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("meh", policyBuilder => policyBuilder
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole("admin")
            .Build());
});
```

##### View.razor

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="meh">
    <Authorized>
        <p>You are authenticated= @context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>
        <p>You ARE authorized.</p>
        <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</p>
        <pre>roles= @context.User.Claims.Single(s => s.Type == "roles").Value</pre>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>You are authenticated= @context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>
        <p>You're not authorized.</p>
        <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</p>
        <pre>roles= @context.User.Claims.Single(s => s.Type == "roles").Value</pre>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

[image]

The output in the DevTools console in Edge is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (admin)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at what the `RequireRole()` does [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/099bc84939fec64e803ec173dac6aa8ceb46a8cc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L163), you'll see that it adds a [`RolesAuthorizationRequirement`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/099bc84939fec64e803ec173dac6aa8ceb46a8cc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs) for given roles(s). If you look at it's `HandleRequirementAsync`, you can see it calls `context.User.IsInRole(role)` to check whether the user is in a given role.

Further, if you look at the `ClaimsPrincipal`'s `IsInRole` method [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs#L765), you can see that it checks whether any identity contains a claim with key defined on that identity as a role claim with given value.

So check your Identity, see what kind of RoleClaimType is defined on it and verify that given claim with given value is present on that identity.

An easy way to debug this and see how your identity looks like when it's passed into the `AuthorizationHandler` is for example using `RequireAssertion` and placing a breakpoint there, e.g.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("meh", policyBuilder => policyBuilder
            //.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            //.RequireRole("admin")
            .RequireAssertion(ctx =>
            {
               // Some custom assertion for your "meh" policy
               // Put a breakpoint here to check what is passed as context.
               return ctx.User.Claims.Single(s => s.Type == "roles")?.Value == "admin";
            })
            .Build());
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I hit the breakpoint and the type is _roles_, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uLI2.png). What bugs me, is that in the `AddMsalAuthentication` call I've included `options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles"` and it did not work with `.RequireRole(roleName)`. I am hesitant to use RequireAssertion for this because RequireRole is the intended use case for this, why is it not working?

Comment: This is getting ridiculously complicated, here are some [more docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/microsoft-entra-id-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=graph-sdk-4). I give up, [I am now using an assertion, which worked at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJRWh.png).

Comment: Glad you got it working. Also have in mind that `IsInRole("admin")` checks for a claim with value `admin`. You have a claim with value `['admin']`, which is different. Remember you can add multiple claims with the same key, i.e. role:admin, role:user, role:owner, etc. And IIRC it's the way that identities are handled by default, so that you don't have to manually deserialize them and then the default `IsInRole` will work just fine. If you want some custom implementation with array values, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and explains why it's not working. I guess my expectation was that within the MS/Dotnet/Entra world it would "just work". My token clearly states the roles property as an array of strings. Multiple app roles can be assigned. Also, the Web API receiving the access token with the roles in the same format, has absolutely no problem handling it, deserializing is implicit there I guess. This is inconsistent behavior between client and server side auth logic, although the same libraries are used